# Can connect to wifi but no internet on Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04

I am on kubuntu 15.04 and I can connect to a network but I cannot access the internet. I can ping my local IP address and KDE Connect works just fine with my phone, but I cannot ping a website or go online via a firefox or chromoum or lynx. The output of come commands similar threads ask for

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
$ sudo iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I have no idea what to do. This happens on more than one network and several reboots and removing/adding the connection have not helped at all. Any help helps. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Where is `traceroute 8.8.8.8`

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  29.937 ms  35.301 ms  35.300 ms
 2  96.120.66.97 (96.120.66.97)  45.589 ms  49.765 ms  50.160 ms
 3  68.86.237.9 (68.86.237.9)  50.803 ms  51.568 ms  51.568 ms
 4  68.85.106.29 (68.85.106.29)  63.827 ms  56.057 ms  63.820 ms
 5  68.86.90.217 (68.86.90.217)  63.818 ms  65.383 ms  65.010 ms
 6  68.86.83.98 (68.86.83.98)  63.802 ms  17.621 ms  18.857 ms
 7  23.30.206.126 (23.30.206.126)  31.115 ms  26.345 ms  29.333 ms
 8  209.85.244.145 (209.85.244.145)  31.238 ms 209.85.244.147 (209.85.244.147)  34.369 ms 209.85.244.157 (209.85.244.157)  31.377 ms
 9  8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8)  31.059 ms  33.854 ms  32.818 ms
```

And traceroute www.google.com

```
www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `www.google.com' on position 1 (argc 1)
```

**SOLUTION**

I added `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` via gui, which did nothing. I prepended `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolv.conf` and then I was able to get online.

Comment: Plese give us outout from command `traceroute 8.8.8.8` and `traceroute www.google.com` Maybe your dns do not resolve names. Put output in your question.

Comment: @2707974 I posted the output.

Comment: Problem make you dns setting. Put for dns servers `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`

Comment: @2707974 Didn't help. Other ideas?